# image fade on click

Tags: jquery, image, fade

HTML :

```
<img class=change src="http://{{$image_server}}/web/product/medium/{{$prod_info.image_medium}}" style='width:380px;' />
```

JQUERY :

```
var images = [ "01.jpg", "02.jpg", "03.jpg" ];

$(function() {
    index = 0;
    $('.change').click(function(e) {
    var image = images[index++];
    if(index == images.length) 
       index = 0;
        $('.change').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
            $('.change').attr('src', ''+image); 
              $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
});
```

I used this code for image fade in/out on click.
But, new image didn't fade in on my system.
An old image faded out/in and suddenly appear a new image!
I wanna know how to fade in new image smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

Increase your fadeIn time to get exactly what you want

```
$(function() {
index = 0;
$('.change').click(function(e) {
var image = images[index];
index++;
if(index == images.length) 
   index = 0;
    $('.change').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
        $('.change').attr('src', image); 
          $(this).fadeIn(800);
    });
});
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/K9sHd/1/)

Comment: I can't see difference. :'(

Comment: change the fadeOut and fadeIn timing for your dependency

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()`,

```
$(document).on('click', '.change', function () { 
});
```

Comment: instead of $('.change').click(function(e) { this line put $(document).on('click', '.change', function () {

Comment: $(function() {
        index = 0;
    $(document).on('click', '.change', function () {
        var image = images[index++];
        if(index == images.length) 
           index = 0;
            $('.change').parent().fadeOut(200, function() {
                $('.change').attr('src', ''+image); 
                  $(this).fadeIn(200);
            });
        });
    });